# Does the Google Feed API support returning images from RSS feeds?

Tags: javascript, rss, google-feed-api

I'm trying to use the Google Feed API to return the images from an RSS feed that is only available in XML. Is this possible?  If so, can someone provide an example?

I don't see this discussed in the respective dev documentation: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide

Answer (score 0):

The RSS would contain html links to images unless the images are embed and that would be nasty,  so you just need to reference the image to display it.